# How can I extract column value corresponding to maximum row value in R?

Tags: r, row, max

I need to calculate :
a) the maximum and minimum (temperature) values for every row of my data set(200 such rows). 
b) Every column corresponds to 'Jan', 'Feb' ... 'Dec' (12 columns). Thus, I need to find the month associated with maximum and minimum temperature.

For (a) this works:

```
 i= 1
  temp.max = NULL
  for(i in 1:200)
  { temp.max[i]<- max(temp.data[i,1:12])}
```

Can someone please help me with (b)?

eg. If the dataset looks like :

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun ... Dec
1     2   3   4  12   6       2
```

Max Value is 12. I need to output that, 'May' is the corresponding month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max.col` is handy for this (I've just repeated your first row 3 times to show it works for multiple rows):

```
names(dat)[max.col(dat,ties.method="first")]
#[1] "May" "May" "May"
```

data used:

```
dat <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,12,6,2),nrow=1)),month.abb[1:7])
dat <- dat[rep(1,3),]
```

Comment: ... but the OP said they need to do this for a data frame with 200 rows ...

Comment: @BenBolker - it's vectorized.

Comment: cool. You learn something every day.  Interesting that there's no `min.col` ... are you just supposed to multiply by -1?

Comment: @BenBolker - I usually just put a -ve sign in front, yep. A bit clunky admittedly.

Answer (score 0):

```
maxvals <- apply(mydata,1,max)
maxlocs <- colnames(mydata)[apply(mydata,1,which.max)]
```

and similarly for `min`/`which.min`

By the way, your solution to (a) puts you in the second circle of Patrick Burns's [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf); the inefficiency probably won't matter in this application but could come back to bite you later ...

Comment: Hi! The code is working. However, I am not able to iterate across the 200 rows I have. This is the code :                                                                    i= 1
  temp.max = NULL
  for(i in 1:200)
  {maxvals <- apply(litter[i,1:12],1,max)
  maxlocs <- colnames(litter[i,1:12])[apply(litter[i,1:12],1,which.max)]
  }

Comment: you don't need to do it 200 times! Just `L <- litter[,1:12]; apply(L,1,max)` and `colnames(L)[apply(L,1,which.max)]` -- or use @thelatemail's slightly more efficient answer.

Comment: Hi! I am running into an error which says : "invalid subscript type 'list'. Can you please help me?